# Unexpected VLOOKUP & MATCH behaviour

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When using 0.1025 as the lookup_value for VLOOKUP or MATCH functions, the formulas only seem to work when the value is hardcoded as a number. If referencing the value from another cell, the formulas produce #N/A errors. Strangely, the problem seems to be eliminated if ROUND is applied to the reference cell first. Another solution that works is if the cell value is first multiplied by 100 then by it's reciprocal and yet 2 or 5 does not work. Similar behaviour happens with 0.0875, 0.1175 and 0.1425.

The problem is exemplified by the formulas shown here.

Copy below and paste to cell A1.

```
0.1025  =CEILING(A3,0.0025) =A1=B1
0.14821 =VLOOKUP(B1,A:B,2,0)    
0.10163 =MATCH(B1,A:A,0)    
        =MATCH(0.1025,A:A,0)    
        =MATCH(ROUND(B1,4),A:A,0)   
        =MATCH(10.25/100,A:A,0) 
        =MATCH((B1*100)/100,A:A,0)  
        =MATCH((B1*2)/2,A:A,0)
```

Above produces results as shown below.

```
0.1025  0.1025  TRUE
0.14821 #N/A    
0.10163 #N/A    
        1   
        1   
        1   
        1   
        #N/A
```

Why?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. Did you check the format of your original cell (number, text...)? your regional settings (comma or dot for decimal separator)? does it work for a natural number?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vlookup lookup ranges have to be sorted ascending, not sure about match. I am reproducing

Comment: Also, I used `=VLOOKUP(B1,A1:A3,1,FALSE)` and it still returned `#N/A`

Comment: JMax: I did check formatting was fine. UK regional settings are fine. It has worked in all cases for many applications, this is the first time I've experienced this issue.

Raystafarian: No, the need to be sorted in ascending order was for the old LOOKUP functions. VLOOKUP overcomes this since you can force it to make an exact match with 0 (or FALSE as you state) as the range_lookup type.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (because I've run into this issue myself a myriad of times and your solution is the one we used) it has to do with precision values in Excel.  Anytime I deal with decimals I am forced to "test" if Excel is treating my values as they are displayed or if micro-values are secretly there, too.

We use the ROUND(), MROUND(), CEILING() and FLOOR() functions to precisely "reset" values before they are further used for this very reason.

0.1025 may really be that, unless you start formatting that cell for 8-10 decimal values... do more numbers appear?

You can frustratingly duplicate this very easily. In A1, type  **0.1025**, then in A2 put **0.1026**.
Now try the formula **=EXACT(0.0001, A2-A1)**.
The result will be ***FALSE***.

If you run the EVALUATE FORMULA function on that cell, you will see a micro-value causes the math to be a value of ***0.000100000000000003*** instead of just ***0.0001***.

So, rounding tools correct the displayed value to an ACTUAL value, and that's why we do it.  Yah, Excel!